# Regex to process hexadecimal, ip and timestamp values in a flat file

Tags: regex, go

Input String :

```
IDVal 4273E6D162ED2717A1CF4207A254004CD3F5307B
Posted 2022-12-28 07:35:55
Status 2022-12-28 08:10:11
Entry 94.62.86.22 2022-12-28 11:10:30
Entry 21.12.26.23 2022-12-28 13:10:30
Entry 113.132.26.203 2022-12-28 12:56:30
Entry 31.12.27.22 2022-12-28 12:35:30
IDVal 0D12D8E72DED99EE31BB0C57789352BED0CEEEFF
Posted 2022-12-28 07:30:55
Status 2022-12-28 06:10:11
Entry 51.102.52.36 2022-12-28 07:10:30
IDVal D947623B30C9D6E142E7D90FC7368B1A2A4F5045
Posted 2010-12-27 04:35:55
Status 2010-12-26 03:10:11
Entry 81.287.82.106 2022-12-28 05:10:20
Entry 11.12.147.2 2022-12-28 07:20:30
Entry 91.177.62.236 2022-12-27 07:10:30
Entry 78.102.152.89 2022-12-25 07:10:30
```

each IDVal can have multiple Entry, out of them only the Entry which has the most recent timestamp is needed.
Looking for regex in golang which will process the list and select/capture only hexadecimal value for each IDVal(is hexadecimal), IP(can be IPV4/IPV6) and timestamp ( which is in YYYY-MM-DD HI:MI:SS format) .

So for the **above** Input string it should capture :

```
4273E6D162ED2717A1CF4207A254004CD3F5307B
21.12.26.23
2022-12-28 13:10:30
0D12D8E72DED99EE31BB0C57789352BED0CEEEFF
51.102.52.36
2022-12-28 07:10:30
D947623B30C9D6E142E7D90FC7368B1A2A4F5045
11.12.147.2
2022-12-28 07:20:30
```

I am new to regex the only thing I could think of was :

```
`IDVal\s[0-9a-fA-F]+`g
and 
`Entry\s[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+\s.[0-9]+\-.[0-9]+\-.[0-9]+\s.[0-9]+\:.[0-9]+\:.[0-9]`g
```

but they both are dependent on the assumption that IDVal and Entry words should exist in the list but it may or may not have them. Hence it should be able to Get first Hexadecimal value and then look for first IPV4/IPV6 and timestamp that follows and then skip other Entry(IPV4's/IPV6's) and look for next hexadecimal value and so on .

Also you can make the assumption that we are iterating each line of the Input String in a for loop.

Comment: Is IDVal always the same length?

Comment: currently I see the len() for all of them in the flat file returned 40, so I would say yes its fixed as of today.  I am not sure if it may change in future .

Comment: Also: are you sure the data is hexadecimal? The last four characters say otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on the assumption that `IDVal` is always 40 characters long and the data is always in the same order.

`(?P<idval>\b[A-F\d]{40}\b)(.|\n)*?(?P<ip>\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b).?(?P<date>\b\d{4}(-\d{2}){2} (\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\b)`

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/flkUpw/1)

You can get the desired data from the named capture groups `idval`, `ip` and `date`.

Comment: Thanks but the regex for IP and Date are returning all IP Entries and all time stamps . We want to process as mentioned in the questions description.

Comment: @yinyang Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the question with a different approach.

Comment: The input string is wrong here : https://regex101.com/r/IWCYrv/2 , that is the values it should capture

Comment: @yinyang fixed that for you

Comment: Thanks but it is still higlighting in blue lines for Posted , Status and the text "Entry"   . Very close though

Comment: @yinyang "You can get the desired data from the **named capture groups** idval, ip and date." capture groups are basically submatches.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) , any online tutorials/resources you can recommend to become a pro like yourself without having to do phd in regex?

Comment: Glad it worked out for you! [regexone](https://regexone.com/) and [regex101](https://regex101.com/quiz/) have nice interactive exercises to learn the basics. The advanced stuff you can lean on SO

Comment: @yinyang Please note that under no circumstance should you use `(.|\n)*?`. See [my YT video with explanation why](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEobSs-ZCSE). Use `.*?` and add `(?s)` at the pattern start.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew I did saw your video . I want the above regex to work for both IPV4 and IPV6 and also only select the "Entry" with the most recent timestamp, I have made updates in the question above. Not sure if I should ask a separate question for that ? . Please help.

Comment: It is Go, so just add `(?s)` at the start and replace all `(.|\n)*?` with `.*?`.