# Regex to process multiple entries for a digital signature

Tags: regex, go

I have the regex and corresponding match output here :
https://regexr.com/6jiei

```
Which matches IP and time stamp for all entries currently but I also want the hexadecimal value for identification.
```

For ex for below **Input string**:

```
IDVal 4273E6D162ED2717A1CF4207A254004CD3F5307B
Posted 2022-12-28 07:35:55
Status 2022-12-28 08:10:11
Entry 94.62.86.22 2022-12-28 11:10:30
Entry 21.12.26.23 2022-12-28 13:10:30
Entry 113.132.26.203 2022-12-28 12:56:30
Entry 31.12.27.22 2022-12-28 12:35:30
IDVal 4273E6D162ED2717A1CF4207A254004CD3F5307B
Posted 2022-12-28 07:35:55
Status 2022-12-28 08:10:11
Entry 94.62.86.22 2022-12-28 11:10:30
Entry 21.12.26.23 2022-12-28 13:10:30
Entry 113.132.26.203 2022-12-28 12:56:30
Entry 31.12.27.22 2022-12-28 12:35:30
IDVal 0D12D8E72DED99EE31BB0C57789352BED0CEEEFF
Posted 2022-12-28 07:30:55
Status 2022-12-28 06:10:11
Entry 51.102.52.36 2022-12-28 07:10:30
```

Output should match/capture :

```
4273E6D162ED2717A1CF4207A254004CD3F5307B
94.62.86.22 2022-12-28 11:10:30
21.12.26.23 2022-12-28 13:10:30
113.132.26.203 2022-12-28 12:56:30
31.12.27.22 2022-12-28 12:35:30
4273E6D162ED2717A1CF4207A254004CD3F5307B
94.62.86.22 2022-12-28 11:10:30
21.12.26.23 2022-12-28 13:10:30
113.132.26.203 2022-12-28 12:56:30
31.12.27.22 2022-12-28 12:35:30
0D12D8E72DED99EE31BB0C57789352BED0CEEEFF
51.102.52.36 2022-12-28 07:10:30
```

I tried this regex :

```
(?s)(\b[A-F\d]{40}\b).*?(\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b).?(\b\d{4}(-\d{2}){2} (\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\b)
```

It then returns the hexadecimal digital signature, but then it only returns the first Entry and doesn't returns all the corresponding entries.

Comment: "that one" is not deleted, you deleted a third one. (I commented on the third one, after deletion I was shown that you have asked "that one" as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to process hexadecimal, ip and timestamp values in a flat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71774786/regex-to-process-hexadecimal-ip-and-timestamp-values-in-a-flat-file)

Comment: @cyberbrain got it , yes kind of similar to the link to the question I had. But I want all Entries for an IDVal this time, instead of just the first occurence .  Please refer the qn description for input string and expected output. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you handle groups and backreferences? @yinyang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start building your query from the back.

**Case 1**: `4273E6D162ED2717A1CF4207A254004CD3F5307B`:

- multiple alphanumerical characters of length 40, as hinted by your regex attempt: `[\w]{40}`

**Case 2**: `113.132.26.203 2022-12-28 12:56:30`:

- a set of numbers and ":": `[\d:]+`,
- a space,
- a set of numbers and "-": `[\d-]+`
- a space,
- a set of numbers and ".": `[\d\.]+`

**Final regex**:

```
"([\w]{40}|[\d\.]+ [\d-]+ [\d:]+)$"
```

Tested on: https://regex101.com/

Does it work for you?

================================================================
**EDIT**: matching with context of the key field

Another option is to check whether `Entry` or `IDVal` is at the beginning of the line you need to match:

```
(?:Entry |IDVal )(.*)
```

Hence, your code should look like the following:

```
pattern := '(?:Entry |IDVal )(.*)'
regex   := regexp.MustCompile(pattern)
matches := regex.FindAllStringSubmatch(str1, -1)
```

The variable `matches` will contain arrays of length two `[[m1,g1], [m2,g2], ... ]` where each list will contain the match `m<i>` and the group `g<i>`. Your information will be contained inside the corresponding group `g<i>`.

Comment: Thanks lemon, it worked :) . why do we need $ ( end of line or string in the regex ) ? . Also please tell me some good online tutorials apart from regexr/regex101 . I have done some online courses still struggling with regexes .

Comment: The end of line is needed otherwise `[\d\w]{3}[\d\w]+` will match words like `IDVal`, `Posted`, `Status`, `Entry`. Though you can modify the regex by increasing the cardinality of `[\d\w]{3}` to say `[\d\w]{6}` or maybe match the exact number of letters/numbers if that is constant (and remove the `$`). Loved a lot the tutorial at https://regexone.com/, check it out when you have time. Good to hear my help was useful!

Comment: Not sure why it gives me false for : re.MatchString(data.String()) ( my data is byte buffer) . I do see that the above regex is for go so not sure why it returns false.

Comment: Can you share a snippet with the code, your input, your output and the expected output? I've never practised go language but maybe I can help you more on the topic with some extra info @yinyang

Comment: Sure : https://go.dev/play/p/OHf08TB4pZa . I want to be able to get/print  IP and timestamp for each Hexadecimal signature. Like mentioned in the "Output should match/capture :" section in description above. Thanks

Comment: Try now: https://go.dev/play/p/TIMt3WDuqfO. Fixes: added "\n" between lines, reduced the amount of strings, changed the regex avoiding the $ as suggested in the second comment of this thread. Let me know if it works for the whole. @yinyang

Comment: Hi lemon, https://go.dev/play/p/AobvMZnRq6m . This is what I meant , that we don't have just one entry of IDVal , it is recurring entry please refer the link. I have also updated the Input string and expected output in the question description above. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, it's clear. Just updated the answer: in your regex attempt I've noticed that you pointed that the length for the `IdVal` field is 40 (is this assumption correct?), hence exploited this information to get a working regex for your updated input. Does it work for you? @yinyang

Comment: There are more cases that should be excluded from the regex matches, update the question so that it includes the other cases too for other people to read. Also I've added an `EDIT` section to my answer that may catch your `IDVal` and `Entry`, but not `ExitAddress`. @yinyang

Comment: what I meant is that: IDVal = ExitNode , Posted = Published , Status = LastStatus , Entry = ExitAddress . It's the same just renamed. It should be name neutral .

Comment: I'm unable understand what you need to match man, I'm sorry. My suggestion is to update your problem statement and set the problem as unanswered, so that you let other people know that you have an open problem. Hopefully someone will manage to handle it. @yinyang